# Reclassifying "service area" in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, reclassify, error-000864

I have created service area from few point, and now I would like to reclassyfy it, but when i try to do it I can see the message:

> ERROR 000864 Input raster: The input is not within the defined domain.
>
> ERROR 000863: Invalid GP data type

but on this **[picture of process](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000st000000)** I can see that this is possible to do: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?id=4850&pid=4849&topicname=Understanding_reclassification How can I do it?

I am using ArcGis10.

The process that i took is as follows:

1. pioints+network
2. created service area, but i would like to reclassify the data
3. i guess now i should use option "convert polygon to raster" to be able to reclassify
4. but then i need to "union" and the problem is that the input data can only be polygons

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to include the precise steps that you have performed, please?  Also, you referred to ArcGIS 10.0 documentation (in Spanish) but are you using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 or a later version?

Comment: What *is* the data type? go to properties in catalog and look at the data type.

Comment: Service area implies (to me) the Network Analyst tool, which generates polygon (vector) output. If that is what you used, did you then convert the service area polys to a raster? The Reclassify tool only works with raster data, not vector. As the other comments mention, we need to know more about your data and the steps you've taken, or even the general goal of what you're trying to do in order to help. Screenshots or samples may help.

Comment: @Chris W i have added some details.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000sr000000) the statistics must be build prior to reclassify, but that is unlikely to cause these error messages.

The error message you are getting suggests the remap type does not match the raster type... if you have an integer raster then you should be using RemapValue, and likewise with floating point raster you should be using RemapRange as unique values don't really exist in the raser.

If the raster is the wrong type for your remap you can convert either way using [float](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Float/009z0000008w000000/) or [int](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Int/009z0000008z000000/).

Answer (score 1):

Reclassify is a raster tool, and based on the process you have so far described it doesn't look like you need to do anything with raster. In order to reclassify vector data, you simply need to alter the existing attributes (not recommended) or create a new 'classification' attribute (recommended).

Let's say you have created service areas at 5, 10, and 15 minutes from your points. You want to label them as good, ok, and bad. Export your service areas to polygons (as I note you have already asked another question about), open the attribute table of those polys, and add a new field text field `rating`. Using select by attribute, select all the 5 minute polys and field calculate `rating` to "good". Then repeat for the other times. The same principle applies if you're wanting to do math with the service area attributes (you don't mention exactly what/how you're trying to reclassify).

You can then run Union on your 'reclassed' polys and whatever other data you're wanting to combine it with. Yes, you could convert everything to raster and work with the raster calculator, but based on what you've described so far I see no reason to do so.